# I'm having trouble listing the category and subcategory

Tags: php, mysql

While I am listing the categories, I try to add the sub-categories next to the main category.

> For example, I try to make it like the category list in the Opencart
>   management panel.

My table in the database is as follows

```
table:
id      - parent_id         - title             - description
1       -  0                -  Desktops         - bla bla...
2       -  0                -  Laptops          - bla bla...
3       -  1                -  Mac              - bla bla...
4       -  1                -  PC               - bla bla...
5       -  2                -  Notebooks        - bla bla...
6       -  5                -  Macs             - bla bla...
7       -  6                -  Windows          - bla bla...
```

I want the category outputs like this

```
Desktops        
Desktops  >  Mac        
Desktops  >  PC     
Laptops & Notebooks     
Laptops & Notebooks  >  Macs        
Laptops & Notebooks  >  Windows
```

http://prntscr.com/rob2fz

This is my code side

```
<?php
$cat1 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER BY id DESC');
   foreach ($cat1 as $v) {
  $cat2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE parent_id = '.$v['id'].' ORDER BY id DESC';
  foreach ($cat2 as $vl) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td width="20"><?php echo $vl['id']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $vl['title']; ?> > <?php echo $v['title']; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#<?php echo $v1['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Edit</a>
    </td>  
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: See about joins.

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can do it with a single database call. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @TheImpaler MySQL 5.x

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to alter your column `parent_id` and replace the zeros by `NULL`, this way you could make this column a foreign key to be sure you never have a `parent_id` that references nothing.

Then you could use this query :

```
SELECT c.title, p.title as parent_title, c.description, p.description as parent_description
FROM category c 
JOIN category p ON c.id = c2.parent_id
ORDER BY p.title, c.title
```

This way you would get the information of the category and the parent in a single query. Beware, though, this code does not works anymore if your parents have parents too.